# Probability of randomly selected person

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I would like some help with some problem i saw on a book,
Given that there is 80% of a customers has a Salary account on bank (lets call this P(A)), and 50% of the customers have a saving account ( P(b) )?

1. What is the chance of random selected person has both save and salary account?
2. What is the chance of random selected person has save but NO salary account?
3. What is the chance of random selected person has only one type of account ?

Regarding:
 1 and 2, im between using the P(A).P(B)  OR P(B|A) = P(A).P(B) / P(A)

Comment: Are we assuming $A$ and $B$ are independent?

Comment: thats the only information i got from the question.So i assume yes.

Comment: The *only* way that we can have any hope of having a single answer rather than a range of answers is to assume that the events are independent.  In such a situation, we are asking what is $Pr(A\cap B)$ for the first problem which by the independence assumption would expand as $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B) = 0.8\times 0.5 = 0.4$.  Without that independence assumption, we could not answer definitively.  We would be able to say that there is anywhere between an $0.3$ and an $0.5$ chance that they have both with every value between possible.

Comment: As an aside, $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\times P(B)$ is true if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  The more correct statement that works regardless of independence is that $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\times P(B\mid A)$.  Now... you wrote "*im between using... P(B|A) = P(A).P(B) / P(A)*"  You should notice that that formula makes little sense to write like that since you could just cancel P(A) from top and bottom and would have simply been written as $P(B\mid A) = P(B)$ which is incorrect if the events are not independent.  What is correct is $P(B\mid A) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, i would assume the Pr(A∩B)=Pr(A)×Pr(B).
About 3rd point any hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $A$ and $B$ are independent,

1. $\mathbb P(A\cap B) = \mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)=\frac45\cdot\frac12 = \frac25$.
2. $\mathbb P(B) - \mathbb P(A\cap B) = \frac12 - \frac25 = \frac1{10}$.
3. $\mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B) - 2\mathbb P(A\cap B) = \frac45 + \frac12 - 2\cdot\frac25 = \frac12$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but shouldnt point 2. be 
0.5 - 0.4 = 0.1 ?

Comment: @Noize I've fixed the error, thanks.

Comment: I'm the one saying thanks, and i assume then the 3. point i would use 2*(1/10) instead too.
Thank you very much

Comment: @Noize Actually, it would be $2\cdot\frac25$. I have updated my answer.